# how to detect shake event when my phone is in lock state

Tags: android, service, shake

I read this [unable to detect shake event when my phones screen is off in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372367/unable-to-detect-shake-event-when-my-phones-screen-is-off-in-android) article. But this question is differ from this.

I created an application which speak (using TextToSpeach API) time when I shake device. For that I have created a "Service" in which "ShakeListener" was registered. While I shake device, it will speak current time.

But this works fine while my device is "ON". When I lock my device, it stops working. Can any one elaborate what is the problem behind?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that when you lock the device, it goes to sleep mode. And your ShakeListener doesn't receive shake events. The best way to implement what you want would be to register broadcast receiver to receive shake events. But as I know, android doesn't provide such broadcast. Another solution is to acuire a partial WakeLock. It'll prevent android from sleep. But of course it'll cause battery issues. Also take a look on this thread: [Android accelerometer not working when screen is turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982433/android-accelerometer-not-working-when-screen-is-turned-off)

Comment: is there any solution to over come this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can not receive this notification until you patch some kernel implementation. Android doesn't broadcast such notification.